# How to calculate the average difference of date between two column

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, filter, average

I have two column of dates, start_date and end_date. I need to know the average days between the two. Some of the dates are blank and should be excluded from the result.

Sample Data (expecting an average of 2 days):

| start_date | end_date |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-19 | 2022-08-21 | 2 |
| 2022-08-21 |  |  |
| 2022-08-15 | 2022-08-18 | 3 |
| 2022-08-18 | 2022-08-19 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(DAYS(B2:B100, A2:A100), B2:B100<>""))
```

[image]

Comment: yep that worked, and it's also much easier to read than the ARRAYFORMULA solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

ArrayFormula turned out to be helpful for this one. After searching a bunch, this formula worked for me:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGE(IF(ISBLANK(B2:B100), "", DAYS(B2:B100, A2:A100))))
```